# Does having decent swim speed from spell, item, power, racial or class ability allow you to propel yourself out of the water?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

Does having decent [swim](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Swim) speed from spell, item, power, racial or class ability allow you to propel yourself out of the water?

> Swim
> A creature with a swim speed can move through water at its indicated speed without making Swim checks. It gains a +8 racial bonus on any Swim check to perform a special action or avoid a hazard. The creature can always choose to take 10 on a Swim check, even if distracted or endangered when swimming. Such a creature can use the [run action](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Run) while swimming, provided that it swims in a straight line.

Note: See the [Swim skill](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/swim) for further details.

For example the [Aegis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/) [Astral Skin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits/) adds +10 feet to the average medium creature's Base Speed of 30 feet making it 40 feet, with the [run action](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Run) (40 x 4 = 160 feet) that's a 160 feet. Is that enough speed to propel you out of the water as if doing a [long or high jump](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics)...say to get you aboard a pirate ship?

Comment: I'd have to look into the rules but I'd apply the same or similar rules that cover long jumping to determine if a swimmer can do this.

Answer (score 4):

This situation is covered under what should be the normal vertical jump rules. Just make sure you calculate based on water speed instead of base speed since above 30 speed gives bonus to check, while movement under gives a penalty.

So lets say the railing of the pirate ship is 10 feet above the surface of the water. Assuming your going to be moving under the water to take advantage of DC's not doubling, you would need a acrobatics check of 40 ([10 feet times 4 per foot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/Acrobatics/#jumping-and-falling)).

There are no specific rules for jumping out of the water, and the normal rules for jumping don't specific their only for land, which is why I have applied them. Even the 3pp rules on the page only cover jumping into water, not out of.